# Styling data by specific values

Tags: carto, geocoding

hoping someone can help me with some styling on a map I've created. I'm rather inexperienced here, but feel rather close to success so hopefully this is a layup for someone who knows what they're doing.

Im basically trying to style my data exactly as I want it, which is uneven intervals. Is there a way to input what I'd like the intervals to be, as I'm able to when I create my legend, and have custom intervals color coded on the map? Currently, I have US counties and customer zipcodes populating the map for me, with a range of 1-1700 per county. I've got 7 buckets and equal intervals on my map, but not sure if quantiles, jenks, or categories would be better, not too much changes as I select them.

Comment: CartoCSS is what you want to use...

Answer (score 1):

You need to switch from `VALUES` to `CartoCSS` mode in the layer `STYLE` tab. Then you need to customize your code using conditionals as explained [in this guide](https://carto.com/learn/guides/styling/basic-cartocss-for-map-styling/).